# "unexpected number of rows (0), Entities may have been modified..." when calling SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net-entity-data-model, savechanges, optimistic-concurrency

I have a simple WPF grid which loads data from a DB using Entity Framework and I need to allow the user to edit the data in the grid an save the updates to the DB.

Unfortunately when I try to save the updates by calling SaveChangesAsync() I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

The call is made in one of my ViewModel classes:

```
...   

   List<Adjustment> changesList = [ here I load the current content of the GridControl ]

   MyDbProxy dataProxy = new MyDbProxy();

   await dataProxy.SaveAdjustments(changesList);
```

and the class that wraps the DB is very simple:

```
public class MyDbProxy {
   private readonly MyDb _db;

   public MyDbProxy() {
      _db = new MyDb();
   }
...
   public async Task SaveAdjustments(IEnumerable<Adjustment> changesList) {
      using (_db) {
         foreach (var a in changesList) {
            _db.Adjustments.Attach(a);
            _db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
         }
         await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this exception throw because you create a new object and tell EF that its modified using the EntityState.Modified